# Apache : Port 80 in use by ""c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 1492

Tags: apache

Please someone can help me to solve this problem step-by-step.

```
11:23:28 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:23:28 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:23:28 AM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
```

[image: I have added image here.]

Answer (score 2):

This happens sometimes, give this a try:

1. Click "Config" button
2. Select "httpd.conf" from the dropdown.
3. On the line where it says "Listen 80" change that to "Listen8080"
4. Save the file.
5. Close the file.
6. Open browser and type " localhost:8080 "
7. Smile because it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed Apache already before installing XAMPP. The error is because Apache is configured to work with a particular port.

The best way to solve this would be to stop the old Apache service from running.

> Go to control panel->administrative tools->services and look for
>   Apache.
>
> Under the Status tab it says **Running**.
>
> Click on it and set it to stop.
>
> Now restart your Xampp and start Apache.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is another apache process running which has the access to the port.

Have you tried using task manager to stop this process?

Also,  you can look in control panel->administrative tools->services

You could have installed apache as a windows service which is started by default on boot up.