# xampp error when start apache says stop apache

Tags: apache, xampp

The error
[image: The error message]
[Apache]    Problem detected!
[Apache]    Port 80 in use by ""C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 20232!
[Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
[Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
[Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

i've try for 1 week to fix it but i cant
i try to stop apache from the service and go to

> xampp\apache\apache_uninstallservice.bat

and uninstall

and then reinstall by

> xampp\apache\apache_installservice.bat

Comment: This may help you solve your question. [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295707/apache-port-80-in-use-by-c-xampp-apache-bin-httpd-exe-k-runservice-with)

Comment: nope, i saw that question before

Answer (score 0):

You have Apache instated twice on your computer.  Delete one of the installs and the other will work.